# Chrome Sometimes Fails To Open On Jenkins Server RobotFramework Tests

Tags: google-chrome, jenkins, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

Our Robotframework test suites run every night against our websites. For the last few weeks there have been very random failures at the start of some tests with the following error just as the headless chrome browser goes to open:

```
  (chrome not reachable)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium-browser is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

It is never the same test and seems to happen randomly. In each set of tests, the browser will open, do some tests, then close. This will happen multiple times in a test file. The test suites could sometimes go for days without any issue and then suddenly it will start happening again. I have tired adding some chrome options as suggested from other posts, but the issue still remains. I have also checked and confirmed the server is never under any pressure.

The browser opens will the following code.

```
    ${options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
    ${user_agent}   set variable    --user-agent=Test User
    ${sandbox}      set variable    --no-sandbox
    ${shm-usage}    set variable    --disable-dev-shm-usage
    Call Method    ${options}    add_argument    ${user_agent}
    Call Method    ${options}    add_argument    ${sandbox}
    Call Method    ${options}    add_argument    ${shm-usage}
    open browser  about:blank  headlesschrome    options=${options}
    Set Window Size  1440  1080
```

It is on the second last line where it goes to `open browser` where it sometimes randomly fails with the error.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to change schedule time 2-3 hours forward or backward and then monitor if job fails or not. I assume you are getting this error because Jenkins is starting other jobs at the same time and there are no enough resources to run Chrome.